# Как сделать чтоб код повторял сам себя каждые 5 секунд?

Tags: python

```
import random
rand = random.randint(1, 999)
p_n = rand
if p_n == 11:
    print("Супер вин!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 22:
    print("Супер вин!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 33:
    print("Супер вин!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 44:
    print("Супер вин!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 55:
    print("Супер вин!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 66:
    print("Супер вин!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 77:
    print("Супер вин!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 88:
    print("Супер вин!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 99:
    print("Супер вин!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 111:
    print("Мега WIN!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 333:
    print("Мега WIN!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 444:
    print("Мега WIN!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 555:
    print("Мега WIN!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 666:
    print("Мега WIN!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 777:
    print("Мега WIN!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 888:
    print("Мега WIN!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
elif p_n == 999:
    print("Ультра WIN!")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
else:
    print("Вы проиграли...")
    print(f"Случайное число - {rand}")
```

Comment: Изучите документацию к модулю `time`. Там много интересного.

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB)

Comment: @Vlad, не забудь принять ответ, если он тебе помог.

Answer (score 7):

Используй `time.sleep(5)`, чтобы реализовать твою задумку (ниже будет пример для ещё более точного измерения времени):

```
import random
import time

while True:
    p_n = random.randint(1, 999)
    if p_n in [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]:
        print("Супер вин!")
    elif p_n in [111, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888]:
        print("Мега WIN!")
    elif p_n == 999:
        print("Ультра WIN!")
    else:
        print("Вы проиграли...")
    print(f"Случайное число - {p_n}")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Для высшей точности времени (вместо `time.sleep(5)`):

```
    start = time.time()
    now = time.time()
    while now - 5 < start:
        now = time.time()
```

Бонус 2-го примера в том, что пока отсчитывается время, можно делать какие-то операции (добавить их во внутренний цикл `while`), в то время, как в 1-ом примере - нет.

Comment: Что-то до меня никак не доходит — зачем нужно `p_n = rand`? Одного `rand` вполне хватает...

Comment: @Глеб А, ну да. Сейчас исправлю. Готово. Я сделал везде `p_n` вместо везде `rand`.

Comment: @Vlad, не забудь принять ответ, если он тебе помог.

Comment: Если вы хотите попросить автора вопроса принять ответ, это надо делать в комментариях к вопросу, а не к ответу. А так уведомления он не получит.

Answer (score 2):

Все проще простого. Вот:

```
import time

while True:
    print("Do something...")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Не точно 5 сек, но примерно